# C statement with confusing conversion to integer?

Tags: c

In the following code there is an argument that I cant wrap my head around. I am supposed to create a pyramid comprised letters, with each line having a unique letter. Each letter/line is in a consecutive format, so line 1 could be A and line 2 would be B B, and line 3 being C C C.

The trouble is with the first For loop that is used to create the rows of the pyramid. Here is the troublesome portion: (input-'A'+1). "input" is a user assigned character variable. There is also a character variable named "alphabet" which has 'A' assigned to it, but unless I am mistaken that is not whats being used here.

From how my brain sees 'A' in this portion of the code it is a character literal. So with this thinking I created a small program using this portion of the entire statement as a printf statement. The variable "input" is user assigned. When i run it with %c as the conversion specifier it completes with no errors but there is no visible output, and it completes with a beep. When I run it with %d it runs and gives me the integer that I expect when subtracting input from A if they were both integers.

What am i missing? is 'A' being converted to an integer? I dont understand how it works, even though I see that it does work. Here is the original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char input, alphabet='A';
    printf("Enter the uppercase character you want to print in the last row ");
    scanf("%c", &input);
    for (i=1; i<=(input- 'A'+1); ++i) {
        for(j=1; j<=i; ++j)
            { printf("%c", alphabet); }
            ++alphabet;
            printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help in clearing this up for me as I am learning from books and YouTube.

Comment: 'A' in C is the ASCII equivalent of the character A. It is the integer 65 in decimal format. This portion of code takes advantage of the ASCII table and performs arithmetic according to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When composing a title for your question try and explain the problem you're having, not the situation you're in.

Comment: `'A'`  *is* an integer constant, it correspond to the character code of `'A'` in the *execution character set*, which is usually a superset of ASCII, and hence `'A'` has the value 65.

Comment: Instead of having only the original program please [edit] and modify the question so that it also has the code that is puzzling you.

Answer (score 1):

Character literals like `'A'` are actually integers. `char` type is signed 8 bit integer type. `'A'` is equal to `65`. You can check the ASCII table too see which number represent which character. With `i <= (input -'A'+ 1)` the code test how far is the input character from `'A'` basically which is the height of the pyramid. If the input were `'A'` then `i <= (input -'A'+ 1)` would essentially `i <= (65 - 65 + 1)` which is `i <= 1` there for only 1 iteration would happen printing a single `A`.

Since `char` is an integer, therefore `++alphabet` will gives the next character in the alphabet.

The reason you have no output with `printf` with `%c` with your testing is most likely because you try to print a non printable character. Check the ASCII table and try to print some alphabet chars or numbers by using their decimal value. Like `printf("%c", 65)` should output `A`.

This little program will print the uppercase alphabet. Might help you see things more clearly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  for (int i = 65; i < 91; i++)
    printf("%d printed as character is %c\n", i, i);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
65 printed as character is A
66 printed as character is B
67 printed as character is C
68 printed as character is D
69 printed as character is E
70 printed as character is F
71 printed as character is G
72 printed as character is H
73 printed as character is I
74 printed as character is J
75 printed as character is K
76 printed as character is L
77 printed as character is M
78 printed as character is N
79 printed as character is O
80 printed as character is P
81 printed as character is Q
82 printed as character is R
83 printed as character is S
84 printed as character is T
85 printed as character is U
86 printed as character is V
87 printed as character is W
88 printed as character is X
89 printed as character is Y
90 printed as character is Z
```

Comment: When you explain C character values to somebody, please mention that the C standard does not require ASCII to be used. Many common C implementations use it, but students should be aware this is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 0):

Characters in C are stored as integers behind the scenes and every character has a corresponding value which you can see in the ASCII table. You can always print out the character as a %d and you'll get that character's int value. You can use that as an advantage while coding so you can increment, decrement, compare and do any sort of operation you would do with basic integers.

Also, post a copy of the code you are having trouble with so others and me can look for the error.

Comment: When you explain C character values to somebody, please mention that the C standard does not require ASCII to be used. Many common C implementations use it, but students should be aware this is not necessarily the case.